# how to pass the callback function in node.js from android client

Tags: javascript, android, socket.io

I want to send data from socket in android client to node.js server .. 
what ive done in server side :

```
     socket.on('new user',function(data,callback){
        console.log('ON new user');

      if(data in users ){
        callback(false);
       }else {
        callback(true);
        socket.nickname = data;
        users[socket.nickname]= socket;
            UpdateNickNames();
    }
});
```

and on my client  android :

```
         import io.socket.client.IO;
        import io.socket.client.Socket;
       import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
EditText edt;
Button btn;
boolean msg;
private Socket mSocket;
{
    try {
        mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.1.101/");
        Log.v(TAG,"fine");
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.v(TAG,"Error..... "+e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSocket.connect();
    edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            attemptSend();
        }
    });
}
private void attemptSend() {
    String message = edt.getText().toString().trim();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
        return;
    }


    mSocket.emit("new user", message, true);
    Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

but it's crash with error : 
 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event                                                                           ^                                                                                                                                                                                                                       TypeError: callback is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I believe your server-side code looks good. the problem is on the clientside... when you are emiting the "new user" event, make sure its a function you are passing as a parameter, instead you passed a boolean value(true). Try this,

mSocket.emit("new user", message, callback);

Also, based on the callback result you get from serverSide, you do something, else you do something else..

HOPE THIS HELPS!

Comment: aha ... U mean something like this : 
 public void callback(boolean x )
    {   
        boolean y ;
        y=x;
        if(y== blablabla ){
            // code goes here 
        }else{
            // code goes here 
        }
      
    }

Answer (score 0):

I've found The Solution here :

```
            mSocket.emit("new user", message, new Ack() {
            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {
              //Code goes here 
            }
    });

}
```